# Should I set CURLOPT_UPLOAD when I POST file with cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, post, curl, libcurl

When I try to set it, it forces the request method to be PUT.

Here is what I put in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'fileUpload' => '@/home/apache/upload/dummy.sql'
));
```

Or should I ignore the CURLOPT_UPLOAD at all? It said prepare for file upload...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely ignore it. 
`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is just enough to upload a file. The curl library will recognize the file upload and set what's required internally itself.

---

The idea behind `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` is to tell curl to use `PUT` method, add some common file uploading headers for that such as `Expect: 100-continue` header and use chunked encoding to upload a file of unknown size if you are using `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: CURLOPT_UPLOAD not necessarily puts PUT method (actually you can/need to specify the method as well). The phrase made me waste an hour or so of work.

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` to do a `PUT` request didn't work for me together with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, instead setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to "PUT" did the job...